# Excel Conditional Formatting - if/and

Tags: conditional-formatting

I am having trouble with this.

I am trying to condition a first row column based on criteria of cells in columns BK and BL.

Bk shows an appointment date
Bl shows whether they attended or not - "1" will be inputted where they do

What I am wanting to do is to format colum A to go red if the appointment date passes and they have not attended.

I can get this working with `=and(today()>bk5,bl5<1)`

However this, then conditions even the cells that are blank (i.e, for cells where appointments are yet to be arranged are also considered by the above equation)

I tried adding in `bk5 > 0` to the equation to solve the issue but it is of no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bk5<>"", so your formula would look like, 
=and(today()>bk5,bl5<1, bk5<>"")
This will evaluate to FALSE if bk5 does not have any value.

Comment: fantastic, works perfectly. Thanks a lot, much appreciated

Comment: please mark the answer as described in the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). That's how to say thank you here!